# order by with union in SQL is not working

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to order when the data comes from many select and union it together? Such as
In this statement, the vouchers data is not showing in the same sequence as I saved on the database, I also tried it with "ORDER BY v_payments.payment_id ASC" but won't be worked

```
( SELECT order_id as id, order_date as date, ... , time FROM orders WHERE client_code = '$searchId' AND order_status = 1 AND order_date BETWEEN '$start_date' AND '$end_date' ORDER BY time)
    UNION 
    ( SELECT vouchers.voucher_id as id, vouchers.payment_date as date, v_payments.account_name as name, ac_balance as oldBalance, v_payments.debit as debitAmount, v_payments.description as descriptions,  
    vouchers.v_no as v_no, vouchers.v_type as v_type, v_payments.credit as creditAmount, time, zero as tax, zero as freightAmount FROM vouchers INNER JOIN v_payments 
    ON vouchers.voucher_id = v_payments.voucher_id WHERE v_payments.client_code = '$searchId' AND voucher_status = 1 AND vouchers.payment_date BETWEEN '$start_date' AND '$end_date' ORDER BY v_payments.payment_id ASC , time ) 
    UNION 
    ( SELECT return_id as id, return_date as date, ... , time FROM w_return WHERE client_code = '$searchId' AND w_return_status = 1 AND return_date BETWEEN '$start_date' AND '$end_date' ORDER BY time)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the sub-select queries in the union within a `SELECT`

```sql
SELECT id, name
FROM
    (
        SELECT id, name FROM fruits
        UNION
        SELECT id, name FROM vegetables
    )
    foods
ORDER BY name
```

If you want the order to only apply to one of the sub-selects, use parentheses as you are doing.

Note that depending on your DB, the syntax may differ here. And if that's the case, you may get better help by specifying what DB server (MySQL, SQL Server, etc.) you are using and any error messages that result.

Comment: Please check again my sql statement, I think the main problem is in my inner join query that doesn't show me the exact same order of my entries

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the ORDER BY at the end of the statement i.e. you are ordering the final resultset after union-ing the 3 intermediate resultsets

Comment: Yup! I tried this on PHPMyAdmin sql editor it shows me a syntax error and when I tried it on my php file it doesn't show the exact same order.

Answer (score 0):

To use an ORDER BY or LIMIT clause to sort or limit the entire UNION result, parenthesize the individual SELECT statements and place the ORDER BY or LIMIT after the last one. See link below:

[ORDER BY and LIMIT in Unions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html#union-order-by-limit)

```
(SELECT a FROM t1 WHERE a=10 AND B=1)
UNION
(SELECT a FROM t2 WHERE a=11 AND B=2)
ORDER BY a LIMIT 10;
```